# How can I burn Mac OSX compatible DVDs using Windows XP?

Tags: macos, dvd, burning

What is a good DVD burning application for Windows XP that can create an disk that is mountable on Mac OSX?  Of course, free would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/)?

Incidentally, I'm pretty sure OSX will open any Windows DVD format so you shouldn't need to do anything special.  At least I've never has a problem.  I believe there are issues going the other way, OSX->Windows, if you use HFS+.

Answer (score 0):

Mountable? How about [**Free DVD ISO Maker**](http://www.minidvdsoft.com/dvdtoiso/download_free_dvd_iso_maker.html):

[image]

Then in OS X Terminal:

```
hdiutil mount /path/to/file.iso
```

Comment: Angered someone John?

Comment: I edited my question to say disk rather than image.  I need a transportable disk that will mount.

Answer (score 0):

[Nero](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nero9-trial.php) Trial or OEM, [TransMac](http://www.asy.com/scrtm.htm) Trial (15day free)

For nero you need iso with hfs+ instead of dmg

Answer (score 0):

[Macdrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/). I've used it before.. Its a nice solution, however, its is not free.

> Simple and easy to use, MacDrive is a must-have utility for anyone
>   working in a Mac and PC World.
>
> MacDrive gives you hassle-free, seamless access to Mac files on Mac
>   disks directly from Windows. You can open, edit and save files on Mac
>   disks, as well as create new disks and repair damaged ones. MacDrive
>   is like having a Mac interpreter in your PC.

Answer (score 0):

[MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) is not free but it is very full-featured:

> MagicISO is a powerful CD/DVD image file creating/editing/extracting
>   tool. It can open / create / edit /extract CD/DVD image files, and it
>   can convert bin to iso and back.  as well as make ISO file from
>   DVD/CD-ROM or hard disk, and handle bootable information at meanwhile.

[image]